# Entitlement has value not permitted by a provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4, xcode4

After testing my app for the past couple weeks we're finally trying to get the app submitted to the app store.  Prior to submitting, I wanted to get my production push notifications set up.  I went and installed my provisioning profile for production set it in my code identifiers in the XCode build area and launched the app hoping that the production push notifications would work.

The first problem that I'm running into now, is that no matter what provisioning profile I select in the code identifiers, I end up with these error codes:

```
 <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not   permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'aps-environment' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Aug 29 22:12:58 unknown amfid[349] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

I've been trying to figure out the problem for hours and have found no solutions.  I was hoping someone out there could help narrow down a solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try removing all your provisioning profiles from Xcode (in the organizer) and the provisioning website if necessary, then follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) to create new ones.

Comment: There is no entitlements section under "Summary"

Comment: I edited my answer with correct info and a more likely solution.

Comment: It should not have been edited in the entitlements file, however, removing all my provisioning profiles worked.

Comment: I'm relieved that this fixed my problem, yet slightly annoyed that the old "delete everything and start over" voodoo dance is still the correct solution. Oh provisioning profiles, why can't I quit you.

Answer (score 8):

This just happened to me because I signed something with an App Store certificate rather than an ad-hoc certificate. Choosing the correct certificate and then re-archiving fixed the issue.

Comment: Were they the same one?

Answer (score 2):

this is happening quite often recently, when archiving apps from different projects in XCode 5.1

I usually solve it by:

- closing XCode,
- deleting all certificates from my Keychain Access
- double clicking in Finder on the .cer file I need
- open XCode and the related project
- recheck signing options in the project
- rebuild the archive

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error myself on an enterprise application. It was a beta release.

I had registered "Development" for Push Notification, but had never setup the "Production" version with the cert and even though it was a beta, it was a true production deploy with a limited user group.

(for any other "searchers" who might find this question)

Comment: This was my exact problem. I wish I could up vote more times.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I had the right provisioning profile selected in Build Settings > Provisioning Profiles, but didn't have the right certificate selected in Build Settings > Code Signing Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Your Machine Key Chain Has not that project Provision Profile

Do The Staps Below ..

```
#1 Just download the provision profile from developer.apple.com
#2 First modify it and add your current device again ..
#3 Check out your info.plist in your project 
#4 provision profile name and name in info.plist should mach with each other ..
#5 now try i hope u will get your project Done.
```

Comment: This didn't work ... I modified it, redownloaded it ... added it to the device in xcode and it's still showing up with the error.  For #3/#4 i don't see where in the info.plist file the provision profile would show up.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that in Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme, the Archive task was set to use the Debug configuration, not the release/distribution configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Test flight ([http://testflight.com](http://testflight.com/)) it's related with the provisioning profiles on your Mac, you see them via "Organizer" delete all of them and try to Build/Archive your apps with only certificate (the one you want to deploy)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error during an OTA install because I didn't add the Keychain Sharing Entitlement to my Target's Capabilities.

Comment: were you actually wanting to share your keychain with other apps? I don't want to, and am not attempting to, yet I get the error during an Enterprise app install.

Answer (score 0):

In my case error appeared for enterprise application.

1. Remove your app from device
2. Remove your app provision profile from device
3. Install app again
4. Profit

here you can see how to manage provision profile
http://applesliced.com/ask/how-do-i-remove-provisioning-profiles-from-my-iphone

it says Open Settings -> General -> Profiles

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to delete all provisioning profiles from Keychain (searched for iPhone, deleted all), remove the account from xcode and then log back in xcode (Preferences | Accounts)

Answer (score 0):

somehow had `get-task-allow` and `keychain-access-groups` activated.

Was stuck on this for a test flight to external users, the version had been approved by apple (!). Result : no one could install it.

We felt pretty happy about it, and took a long time to understand what was going wrong.