# Can't install enterprise app ipa on iOS8+

Tags: ios, iphone, code-signing

I have an app with a bundle identifier `com.company.app`, I've archived the app and upload it, now when I'm trying to install I get this error:

```
Sep 17 13:30:11 IPhone itunesstored[2199] <Error>: 0x102570000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.5aCjkh/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app identifier = com.company.app type = User App> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)" UserInfo=0x145ec8ed0 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=192, FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.5aCjkh/extracted/Payload/MyApp.app identifier = com.company.app type = User App> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)}
```

So, i've changed my bundle identifier to: `AppIdPrefix.com.company.app` and archived the application again, uploaded it, and suddenly it worked just fine.

But now, I get this error:

```
Sep 17 13:58:35 IPhone SpringBoard[2200] <Warning>: No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'MyApp': (null). Notifications will not be delivered.
```

Also when I set manually the Provisioning Profile and Code Signing Identities like that:

[image]

Then I try to archive and get this error:

[image]

So in one hand, when I try to install without AppId prefix added to bundle it wont install, but on the second hand when I add the AppId prefix it installs the app but the aps-environment won't work.

How could I fix that? I literally searched everywhere and can't find something that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem by doing the next steps:

1. Remove all the Provisioning Profiles from my mac using `iPhone Configuration Utility` app ([download from here](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/iPhone-Configuration-Utility.shtml#download)).
2. Remove all the certificates that are related to this app from the `Keychain Access`.
3. Open `Xcode` and hit `Clean` and `Clean Build Folder` by holding `Alt` while the `Product` menu is open.
4. Restart your mac

Hope that helps. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Please add distribution option for all Code Signing Identity. Make sure you have added proper bundle identifier. Clean code and try again. it will work.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper bundle identifier"? To add it with or without the AppId prefix?

Answer (score 0):

`Sep 17 13:58:35 IPhone SpringBoard[2200] <Warning>: No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'MyApp': (null). Notifications will not be delivered.`

This error corresponds that you are using `Push Notification` in the app, But in Developer account you have not enabled Push notification.Enable it for your AppID

Comment: So to stay with the AppId prefix or to remove it from the beginning of the bundle?

Comment: y are u changing bundle ID.That will not help you.It should be same with your APPID bundle identifier

Comment: when u create an appid in enterprise account.Are u using that same bundle identifier which u have mentioned in ur account

Comment: yes. I do. But when I archive the app it wont install it. it gives me an error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239017/entitlement-has-value-not-permitted-by-a-provisioning-profile-error.check dis